# c++ looping through string

Tags: c++, algorithm

Finally i find solutions in convert lowecase to uppercase and to identify whether the string is alphabet or numeric code as follow:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char ch;
  cout<<"Enter a character: ";
  gets(ch);

  if ( isalpha ( ch ) ) {
    if ( isupper ( ch ) ) {
      ch = tolower ( ch );

      cout<<"The lower case equivalent is "<< ch <<endl;
    }
    else {
      ch = toupper ( ch );
      cout<<"The upper case equivalent is "<< ch <<endl;
    }
  }
  else
    cout<<"The character is not a letter"<<endl;
  cin.get();
}
```

How can i improve the code above to get string rather than a single character? Looping keeps print same statements many times. Thanks

Comment: What is meant by "Looping keeps print same statements many times"?

Comment: An unrelated error: you cannot call the functions in `<cctype>` with a `char`.  You must convert to `unsigned char` first, or suffer undefined behavior.

Comment: @JamesKanze, do you have some docs indicating converting to unsgined char is indeed required? I've found [tolower() reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/) with example where 'char' is used.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I had never problem with using `char` and ctype functions. Why we cannot call those functions with `char`?

Comment: @kamituel Just the C standard.  It specifies that all of the functions in `<ctype.h>` take an `int`, either in the range `[0...UCHAR_MAX]` or equal to `EOF`.  The implicit conversion of `char` to `int` will not necessarily result in a value in this range.

Comment: @MM. It's undefined behavior.  If plain `char` is unsigned, it
will actually work.  Otherwise, you'll get undefined behavior
for any character whose encoding is greater than 127.  (One
implementation I know of actually makes it work for everything
but `0xFF`---`'ÿ;` in Latin-1.  Others probably not.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Here's the cleaner solution which outputs one, single word.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

char switch_case (char ch) {
  if ( isalpha ( ch ) ) {
      if ( isupper ( ch ) ) {
        return tolower ( ch );
     }
     else {
       return toupper ( ch );
     }
   }
  return '-';
}

int main()
{
  string str;
  cout<<"Enter a word: ";
  cin >> str;

  transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), switch_case);
  cout << str << "\n";
}
```

The [std::transform](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) is being used in this example.

---

Just read an entire word and use [std::string::iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) to iterate over one letter at a time:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  string str;
  cout<<"Enter a word: ";
  cin >> str;

  for ( string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it ) {
    char ch = *it;
    if ( isalpha ( ch ) ) {
      if ( isupper ( ch ) ) {
        ch = tolower ( ch );

        cout<<"The lower case equivalent is "<< ch <<endl;
     }
     else {
       ch = toupper ( ch );
       cout<<"The upper case equivalent is "<< ch <<endl;
     }
   }
   else
     cout<<"The character is not a letter"<<endl;
 }
 cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Didn't works..only convert first letter as upercase, if a string contain any lower case it's only convert first letter to uppercase..need to convert all lower to upper

Comment: Not true. The entire word is being converted because I've not really changed your algorithm, just added a for loop.

Comment: result : 
Enter a character: sasas
The upper case equivalent is S

Comment: Okay, when I entered "sasas" I got "SASAS". Is that not correct?

Comment: Please, please, please: calling any of the functions in `<cctype>` with a `char` is undefined behavior.  You _must_ convert any `char` arguments to `unsigned char` first.

Comment: I've just copied the code from my answer, put it into a new file and compiled it with your command - it works. For 'sasas' I get five lines of output "the upper case...". Are you sure you're compiling and running the right code?

Comment: @kamituel this time i got this The upper case equivalent is S The upper case equivalent is A The upper case equivalent is S The upper case equivalent is A The upper case equivalent is S

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: @kamituel it should output like this Enter a word: asas
The upper case equivalent is ASAS . Thanks

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer - not it uses std::transform, and the code is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Firs use the input operator to read into a string:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
```

Optionally you can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to get more than a single word.

Then you can use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to convert the string to upper- or lower-case.

You can also use a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to iterate over the characters in the string.

Comment: Using `std::stransform` can be a bit tricky, since you cannot pass it `toupper` or `tolower` directly.  Any professional programmer who deals with character data will have the necessary functional objects in his tool kit, and use those, but this seems more like a learning exercise than a problem a professional programmer has encountered in his work.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 :

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cout << "Enter data: ";
    cin >> s;

    for (auto &ch : s)
    {
        if (isalpha(ch))
        {
            if (isupper(ch))
            {
                ch = tolower(ch);
                cout << "The lower case equivalent is " << ch << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                ch = toupper(ch);
                cout << "The upper case equivalent is " << ch << endl;
            }
        }
        else
            cout << "The character is not a letter" << endl;
    };
    cin.get();
}
```

or

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin >> s;

    transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), [](char ch)
    {
       return isupper(ch)? tolower(ch) : toupper(ch);
    });
}
```

If you have `g++` try : `g++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++11` to compile.